# What happens to undelivered AlarmManager repeating alarms when phone wakes up?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

If we schedule an inexact repeating alarm with `AlarmManager.setInexactRepeating` to be fired every hour, for example, what happens if the phone is in standby for 4 hours and then it is woken up? Does the system deliver 4 alarms in a row for the same `PendingIntent` or does it deliver only a single alarm?

**EDIT:** reading the documentation with more attention, the `set(int, long, android.app.PendingIntent)` method documentation says: *Alarm intents are delivered with a data extra of type int called `Intent.EXTRA_ALARM_COUNT` that indicates how many past alarm events have been accumulated into this intent broadcast. Recurring alarms that have gone undelivered because the phone was asleep may have a count greater than one when delivered.* 
So, when the phone comes out of standby, only one alarm will be delivered, with an intent extra that contains the number of missed alarms.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the documentation with more attention, the `set(int, long, android.app.PendingIntent)` method documentation says: *Alarm intents are delivered with a data extra of type int called `Intent.EXTRA_ALARM_COUNT` that indicates how many past alarm events have been accumulated into this intent broadcast. Recurring alarms that have gone undelivered because the phone was asleep may have a count greater than one when delivered.* 
So, when the phone comes out of standby, only one alarm will be delivered, with an intent extra that contains the number of missed alarms.

Answer (score 0):

it depends if you use
pending intent like this

```
  PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

it wont trigger 4 times as it cancells the previous pending intent

Comment: I'm not sure but I think that `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` has a meaning only during the creation/retrieval of the pending intent object, not the meaning of avoiding what I've said in the main post.

Comment: To explain better, with that flag you're saying that if you've already created a pending intent that matches the pending intent you're creating now (i.e. the same intent action, data etc), the system cancels the old one and creates a new pending intent object.

Comment: i hope that is what i mentioned it wont trigger four times as it cancels the previous pending intent

Comment: No.. suppose you create the pending intent and then you schedule a repetitive alarm with the `AlarmManager`. So you invoke `PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);` only once in your code, i.e. you do not cancel any existing pending intent at creation time (where the flag `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` is taken into account). Then the `AlarmManager` calls the `send()` method on your pending intent: my problem is to understand if it calls only once and not once for any missed alarm. The flag above is irrelevant in my opinion for what I asked. BTW thanks

Comment: it wont go for four times as the max delay is the entire interval so max probability is two alarms refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: I've updated the main post with information found for the `http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set(int, long, android.app.PendingIntent)`