# How alarmmanager on android schedule the task when using setRepeating when phone shutdown

Tags: android, alarmmanager, schedule

I wanted to know what will happen if the phone shutdown either low battery or user shut it down. If I set the alarm manager to trigger the service for every hours but at some point user shut down the phone, when will the alarm trigger the service again.

If using set instead of setRepeating, I schedule it to trigger the service after 7days, but the phone had shutdown for 3days, does that 3days counted as part of the 7days or does it not count those 3days.

Sorry this is my first time using the Alarm Manager.

Comment: Your alarms are cleared whenever the device powers down. You need to [reset them at boot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673746/start-alarmmanager-if-device-is-rebooted).

Comment: Check -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140824/what-happens-to-undelivered-alarmmanager-repeating-alarms-when-phone-wakes-up